# Doctrine getArrayResult() returns database value while entity getter processes value

Tags: symfony, doctrine

For example:

```
public function getField() {
  return ucfirst($this->field);
}
```

Given that an entity has getters that do some changes on the database value before returning it, how can those changes also be applied when using the getArrayResult() method ?

For example, Laravel has accessors (http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators). The entity getter can be used in the same way.

When using getArrayResult(), the value for the "field" will not have the first character capitalized.

Thank you!

Comment: A getter of an entity SHOULDN'T change anything in the DB! What are you asking to do? It's not clear...

Comment: Of course it should. We should always be productive with our answers instead of randomly throwing invalid advice.

Comment: I agree with @pcm. I found myself in some situations where get/set methods acted as a transformer before persisting and after loading.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's the same behaviour as laravel almost :)
Take a look at [Hydrators](http://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/data-hydrators.html)
.

Hydrators are the processors that bind your raw db output to various data types in doctrine. Thus you have Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_RECORD which is the standard hydrator(aka the thing called when you use $query->getResult()).
If you use $query->getArrayResult(), it uses the Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY Hydrator.

If you need a more detailed description, please let me know.

Comment: Hi, pcm! Thank you for the answer. I (think) am familiar with the Hydrators. The issue I'm having is that when getting an object, the properties on that object (accessed through getters) have a value (that differs from the database value because it was changed by said getter), while when using Array Hydration, since the getter is never called, the value is the one from the database.I want the array result, but I also want the values after they are "processed" by the getters ... Hope that makes sense ... and that I'm not missing anything ... :)

Comment: Well, an array hydrator never outputs an object, thus you have no getters :). It's just raw db output with minor modifications and relations added to the array. If I were you i'd go back to the Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_RECORD so you get an object as output, and use partial selects if you feel like the output is too large.